# Running 'Sweet Home 3d

Tags: system-installation

I am running the latest (everything) of Ubuntu and install all updates as I become aware that of them.

The problem ... I have installed 'sweethome3d' but when I want it to run, it starts and immediately shuts down. I also have another computer running Linux Mint that does the same thing.

What should I do to get this s/w to fully run on either computer?

Thank you in advance.

Gary Hall

Comment: SH3D v5.2a runs on my 16.04 system. What versions do you have? In terminal, type `sweethome3d`, and add the output that you see to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the developer's web site and check out all the Q & A but I found this Version 5.3 Beta 8 most current bug fix for you: ([sweethome3d.com Version 5.3 Beta 8](http://www.sweethome3d.com/support/forum/viewthread_thread,6818_offset,20)).

Besides that link you can look at Version 5.3 Beta 7.